# Auto Generate Audit log Reports in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hello Good Evening Everyone,

In our client requirement ,we need to generate audit log reports regularly or weekly about user activity on our site and get it saved in particular location.

Is there any feature in SharePoint Online through which we can auto generate audit log reports?

Any lead would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately this question is off-topic as written, as it's really not a programming question and more of a documentation-request question.

Answer (score -1):

At present, your requirement cannot be met online. Because Sharepoint online no longer supports this setting.

https://prairiedeveloper.com/2018/12/how-to-auto-generate-sharepoint-audit-reports-the-gui/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIyh8.png)

Audit log research can only be performed manually in the compliance portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. Also, the OP's question is off-topic here - 1) it's not a programming question, and 2) it's written as documentation-seeking. Oh and 3) there are no details at all, other than a general requirement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).